# kill-buffer ERROR: wrong-type-argument - can't programatically kill buffers

Tags: buffers, functions, list

I'm trying to kill buffers after selecting them from `buffer-list`:

```
(kill-buffer
 (cl-remove-if-not (lambda (b)
                     (and
                      (string-match-p "ein" (buffer-name b))
                      (string-match-p "notebooklist" (buffer-name b))
                      )
                     )
                   (buffer-list))
 )
```

Sadly it yields an error: `ERROR: (wrong-type-argument stringp (*ein:notebooklist http://127.0.0.1:8888*))`

If anyone knew how to check what needs to be done to it before giving it to `kill-buffer` function that would be really helpful.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: thanks and sorry, noted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kill-buffer expects a buffer or a buffer name (string) as argument. You're passing it a *list* with only one element: the buffer name.

Pass the **`car`** of that list (its only element) to `kill-buffer`:

```lisp
(kill-buffer
 (car (cl-remove-if-not (lambda (b)
                          (and (string-match-p "ein" (buffer-name b))
                               (string-match-p "notebooklist" (buffer-name b))))
                        (buffer-list))))
```

Answer (score 0):

`mapc` function seems to work - it applies kill-buffer function for every element in the list:

```
 (mapc 'kill-buffer
  (cl-remove-if-not (lambda (b)
                      (and
                       (string-match-p "ein" (buffer-name b))
                       (string-match-p "notebooklist" (buffer-name b))
                       )
                      )
                    (buffer-list))
  )
```